# Highcharts 3 suppor for Android 2.x

Tags: android, highcharts

Has anyone tried using the latest [Highcharts 3.0 beta](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/53-highcharts-3-0-beta-released) (Mar 2013) with a phone running Android 2.x (specifically 2.3)? When I try rendering any of the demo charts from that blog post or using that library inside a WebView, I get nothing. Seems to work perfectly fine in Android 4.x. I changed the library to HC 2.3.5 and the charts are now visible. Is this because the canvas library does not support HC 3? What's the story?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug so I've reported it to our devs here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1612